# Remove default static option from ng-option if number of dynamic options is one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just need to remove the `<option value="">select any item ----</option>` option from dropdown if the object has only one option - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5ckd/169/).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-model="sel" ng-options="d as d.name for d in data" >
        <option value="">select any item ----</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**AngularJS application**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
           {name: 'test1', id: 1},
           {name: 'test2', id: 2},
           {name: 'test3', id: 3}
        ];

        $scope.sel = '';
}]);
```

Comment: can you count them before outputting the drop down options

Comment: Have you figured out our problem?

Comment: no not yet. still searching. you got something?

Comment: Nope, please create a demo to reproduce it :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the option button

```
<option disabled selected value=''>select any item ----</option>
```

Comment: i want to hide not disabled

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ng-if` like in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szca4786/1/).

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-model="sel" ng-options="d as d.name for d in data" >
        <option value="" ng-if="data.length > 1">select any item ----</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
          {name: 'test1', id: 1},
          {name: 'test2', id: 2},
          {name: 'test3', id: 3}
        ];

        $scope.sel = '';
}]);
```

Comment: your answer is working but in my case the default option is last on the list. if object.length is more than 1.

Comment: @AkshayKumar Sorry, I dont understand. What is the problem? This is exactly based on your question code?

Comment: yes i am using your code only... its working fine but my data is dynamic and the example here is static... so the behaviour is different.. My default option is coming in the end after all objects....

Comment: @AkshayKumar Owwwww m8, -.- please edit your question so I will be able to create a correct solution.

Comment: my question is correct only.. and i cant create the fiddle with dynamic data... :(

Comment: Please add the `dynamic data` set into your `$scope.data`. Especially the `default option`. I dont need a fiddle.

Comment: no no.. you are getting me wrong... default option is not dynamic.. but the other options are dynamic....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137063/discussion-between-lin-and-akshay-kumar).

Comment: no no.. you get me wrong... default option is not dynamic.. but the other options are dynamic....